# No application can perform this action during installation APK in android device

Tags: android, apk, failed-installation

I want to install APK file of my application in my android device.

The old APK file is installing correctly but when I am trying to install the latest application file it shows the error like "No application can perform this action."

I already uninstalled the old application from my device.

I have tried to change the Version name and Version Code both after failure in the installation but then also it shows the same error.

This APK file is installing correctly in the other devices.

Can any body please tell me what is the real problem?

Comment: make sure that old apk file is not available on the device.

Comment: Old APK file is in the other devices too but it installs new APK file well in that devices.

Answer (score 2):

After some changes with my application I got result when I renamed my file with filename + .apk

It worked for me.

*filename.apk*

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Package Installer which handles actions to perform apk installation is missing or disabled on the device.